# How to concatenate a msgpack number with a regular string to create a redis key from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-redis, msgpack

I need to create a Redis key which is composed of a string and msgpack concatenated together.

The key looks like this (in redis db):

```
"a:b:c:\xcd\x10\xd8"
```

The message pack portion is this:

```
'\xcd\x10\xd8'
```

(translates to 4312)

my code is similar to this:

```
var msgpack = require("msgpack-lite");
var encoded = msgpack.encode(4312);
key = "a:b:c:" + encoded;
```

I've also tried like this:

```
var b1 = new Buffer("a:b:c:");
var b2 = new Buffer(mspacked);
var parts = [b1, b2];
key = Buffer.concat(parts);
```

the `msgpack` portion is correct until it is concatenated to the string.

I assume that this is an issue with the javascript string type and the way I am trying to handle it

Comment: Have you tried [`String()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp) or [`.toString()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp) ?

Comment: yes. it's not giving the correct result.

Comment: What IS the result you're getting btw?